# New images are not being deployed to AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I've split out the initial `azure-pipelines.yml` to use templates, iteration, etc... For whatever reason, the new images are not being deployed despite using `latest` tag and/or `imagePullPolicy: Always`.

Also, I basically have two pipelines `PR` and `Release`:

- `PR` is triggered when a PR request is submitted to merge to `production`. It automatically triggers this pipeline to run unit tests, build the Docker image, do integration tests, etc. and then pushes the image to ACR if everything passed.
- When the `PR` pipeline is passing, and the PR is approved, it is merged into `production` which then triggers the `Release` pipeline.

Here is an example of one of my `k8s` deployment manifests (the pipeline says `unchanged` when these are applied):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: admin-v2-deployment-prod
  namespace: prod
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: admin-v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: admin-v2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: admin-v2
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          image: appacr.azurecr.io/app-admin-v2:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4001
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: admin-v2-cluster-ip-service-prod
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: admin-v2
  ports:
    - port: 4001
      targetPort: 4001
```

And here are the various pipeline related `.yamls` I've been splitting out:

#### Both PR and Release:

```
# templates/variables.yaml
variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '<GUID>'
  imageRepository: 'app'
  containerRegistry: 'appacr.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  imagePullSecret: 'appacr1c5a-auth'

  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

---

#### PR:

```
# pr.yaml
trigger: none

resources:
- repo: self

pool:
  vmIMage: $(vmImageName)

variables:
- template: templates/variables.yaml

stages:
- template: templates/changed.yaml
- template: templates/unitTests.yaml
- template: templates/build.yaml
  parameters: 
    services:
    - api
    - admin
    - admin-v2
    - client
- template: templates/integrationTests.yaml
```

```
# templates/build.yaml
parameters:
- name: services
  type: object
  default: []

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    steps:
    - ${{ each service in parameters.services }}:
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Build and push an ${{ service }} image to container registry
        inputs:
          command: buildAndPush
          repository: $(imageRepository)-${{ service }}
          dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)/${{ service }}/Dockerfile
          containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
          tags: |
            $(tag)
```

---

#### Release:

```
# release.yaml
trigger: 
  branches: 
    include:
    - production

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
- template: templates/variables.yaml

stages:
- template: templates/publish.yaml
- template: templates/deploy.yaml
  parameters: 
    services:
    - api
    - admin
    - admin-v2
    - client
```

```
# templates/deploy.yaml
parameters:
- name: services
  type: object
  default: []

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Publish
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: 'App Production AKS'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Create imagePullSecret
            inputs:
              action: createSecret
              secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
              kubernetesServiceConnection: 'App Production AKS'
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
          - ${{ each service in parameters.services }}:
            - task: KubernetesManifest@0
              displayName: Deploy to ${{ service }} Kubernetes cluster
              inputs:
                action: deploy
                kubernetesServiceConnection: 'App Production AKS'
                manifests: |
                  $(Pipeline.Workspace)/k8s/aks/${{ service }}.yaml
                imagePullSecrets: |
                  $(imagePullSecret)
                containers: |
                  $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository)-${{ service }}:$(tag)
```

- Both `PR` and `Release` pass...
- The new images are in ACR...
- I've pulled the images to verify they have the latest changes...
- They just aren't getting deployed to AKS.

Any suggestions for what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For whatever reason, the new images are not being deployed despite using latest tag

How should Kubernetes know that there is a new image? Kubernetes config is *declarative*. Kubernetes is already running what once was "latest" image.

> Here is an example of one of my k8s deployment manifests (the pipeline says unchanged when these are applied)

Yeah, it is *unchanged* because the *declarative disered state* has **not** changed. The Deployment-manifest states *what* should be deployed, it is not a command.

### Proposed solution

Whenever you build an image, always give it a unique name. And whenever you want to deploy something, always set a unique name of *what* should be running - then Kubernetes will manage this in an elegant zero-downtime way using rolling deployments - unless you configure it to behave different.

Comment: Thanks, so that is the weird thing. Before I started splitting the system generated `azure-pipelines.yml` into template files, and introducing iteration into the templates, my k8s manifest just had `image: appacr.azurecr.io/app-admin-v2` and it seemed to pull the latest without having to change anything or `imagePullPolicy: Always`. I actually only added the `latest` tag and `imagePullPolicy` to resolve the issue. The `tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'` should be generating a new number for the image and when I check ACR, it looks like it has. Trying without `latest` and will report back.

Comment: well, writing image name without a tag is the same as using `latest`  - what you should do is to create a new tag for every built image.

Comment: I might have to open a separate a question. I'm back to where I was when I first split `PR` and `Release`, and was still using `$(Build.BuildId)` for the image tags: `PR` generates the image with `app-api:543`, but then `Release` can't find it because it is looking for `app-api:544`. Getting around that issue is why I started just using `latest`, but that created the issues outlined above.

Comment: You need to deploy the same "BuildId" that you built. But it sounds reasonable to have one build for PR and another build for Release (after merge).

Comment: It looks like you don't build on the Release pipeline? If that is after git-merge you need to build the app again, and then deploy.

Comment: I now read that both PR and Release is after your merge? Then you just need to have the same number for buildId and in the Release pipeline.

Comment: Right, that much I figure, but I'm trying to implement it so I don't have to manually specify it every-time, it just does it automatically... like when `PR` and `Release` were still part of the same pipeline. Because it was the same pipeline, it had the same `BuildId`, but now that it is split, it is incrementing the `BuildId` for `Release`. Probably a simple solution I'm overlooking. I could add another build for `Release` which would resolve the issue. Slows it down, but that might be what I have to do.

Comment: The flow is PR triggers `PR` pipeline which runs unit tests, builds image, does integration tests, and then pushes to ACR if they pass. The PR is approved and the branch is merged into `production` which triggers `Release` and deploys the images. So there is not another build going on for `Release`... it just uses the images the at passed integration testing from the `PR` pipeline. Maybe not the best flow, but I'm open to suggestions. Pretty new to this.

Comment: if you merge, then you need to build again. Because I think two branches can be merged concurrently, right? It depends on your branch strategy. And it is recommended to then run all tests again.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. Yeah it is possible that another branch could merge concurrently to the `production` branch which just using an image that passed all tests from the `PR` pipeline would miss. Trying to implement trunk-based development with very short-lived branches. Currently I'm just doing `git push production:feature_for_pr` and `feature_for_pr` is deleted when it is merged to `production`.

Comment: Sounds like a good strategy. But yes, then you definitely need to build again after merge, since the code may be different (e.g. another PR was merged right before).

Answer (score 2):

In your deployment you pull
`image: appacr.azurecr.io/app-admin-v2:latest`

Since there is no hash but simply the tag `latest` referenced the deployment says:
"You want latest? I have latest running!".
Important part is the "running". The pull policy `always` doesn't help if there is no need to pull in the first place.

Potential solutions:

- Change something in your deployment that will cause a redeployment of the pods. Then it will actually pull the image again.
- **Cleaner solution**: Don't use latest! Use some semantic versioning or date or whatever strategy matches your approach. In this case the tag will change always and it will always pull that image.